# Laravel disable provider (Clockwork) on fly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, clockwork

I'm having a laravel setup with the [Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) installed.
And I have a artisan command that takes really long time to run, so that clockwork will consume too much memory.
I still need that extension.
How can I disable it when just running a command?

Answer (score 1):

you can override this in the config file clockwork.php

run
php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Clockwork\Support\Laravel\ClockworkServiceProvider'

then apply your condition on 'enable'

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

1. Publish the [clockwork.php](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork/blob/cb1d48b02d0a9bbcbb2fc3be79f9b60d3a2202e9/Clockwork/Support/Laravel/config/clockwork.php#L15) configuration file:
   I.e: Run the command:

```bash
php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Clockwork\Support\Laravel\ClockworkServiceProvider'
```

Then it will give you a *clockwork config file* (*config/clockwork.php*).

2. Use the script below to *temporarily* disable and re-enable clockwork after your "data-intense" commands.

```php
config()->set('clockwork.enable', false);

//  A few data-intense commands here...

config()->set('clockwork.enable', true);
```